# Debugging logos tweak on WKWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, wkwebview, jailbreak, theos

I am trying to create an iOS tweak that makes `WKWebView` run certain JavaScript code after it finishes loading a page. I made a simple iOS app with an embedded `WKWebview`, loading the url as `“https://google.com”` and add the app’s bundle id to the tweak plist. I intent to let the webview evaluate JavaScript code like:

```js
document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'red'
```

...however nothing happened ( as the google’s background should turn into red ). Is there any syntax error or something missing in my code?
By the way, how do you debug a iOS tweak or .x file? I can’t seem to find any log or breakpoint like in Xcode

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>

%hook WKWebview

- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView didFinishNavigation:(WKNavigation *)navigation {
    %orig;
   NSLog(@"Webview did finish loading");
    [webView evaluateJavaScript:@"document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'red'" completionHandler:nil];

}


%end
```

I tried to call [`- [WKWebView evaluateJavaScript:completionHandler:]`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/1415017-evaluatejavascript?language=objc) method as followed by Objective-C syntax. I expect the google's home page to turn red but no change happened

Comment: For one, you misspelled the class name in `%hook WKWebview`, and for another, a quick Google search tells me that `webView:didFinishNavigation:` is an instance method of `WKNavigationDelegate`, not `WKWebView`.